# createLink (absolute:true) produces broken link

Tags: grails

i just saw a strange behaviour inside a Controller in my grails app.

I called `createLink(absolute:true, action:"action", controller:"controller")`

and received

> http://localhost:8080/[:]/controller/action

anyway, the position where my applicationName should appear is filled with "[:]" which i think is a empty Map.

Anyone seend this before? Any solutions?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 3):

I use a environment-depending serverURL configuration in Config.groovy.
For developement and test environtment it is like this :

> grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"

This config-entry is used as prefix while creating a link with `absolute:true` option.

After changing the config file while grails is running grails will not correctly resolve the `${appName}` text-injection and the result will be a `[:]` as applicationName.

So this will only happen if you change the Config.groovy file whill running grails.

Hope this helps if anybody face similar problems ;)

Alex

Comment: There is (at least one) plugin that allows you to change the config while the app is running

Answer (score 2):

Never seen this before, can you check that `Config.groovy` contains

```
grails.app.context = "/${appName}"
```

Also check that `application.properties` contains

```
app.name=yourAppName
```

Comment: The Config was correctly set. Thanks, your hint showed me the right direction.